# Relative complement of a Non CFL to CFL

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Let $L$ be a given Context Free Language over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$. Now consider $$L_1=L-\{xyx\ |\ x,y\in\{a,b\}^*\}$$
I know that $\{xyx\ |\ x,y\in\{a,b\}^*\}$ is not Context Free (by using pumping lemma).

Based on that can we affirmatively say that $L_1$ will **NEVER** be Context Free (can't use closure property here, as $\{xyx\ |\ x,y\in\{a,b\}^*\}$ is neither *CFL* not *Regular*)?

Or shall $L_1$ ALWAYS be Context Free ?

Comment: Be more precise, without further conditions $\{ xyx \mid x,y\in \{a,b\}^* \}$ equals $\{a,b\}^*$.

Comment: Oh man! yes of course ... I missed that point that $x$ can be $\epsilon$. Thanks. So $\{xyx\ ∣\ x,y\in\{a,b\}^*\}$ is indeed **regular** without any bound on $x$ and $y$, and so is $L_1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Shall we close it or should @HendrikJan post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that $\{ xyx \mid x,y \in \{a,b\}^*\}$ is in fact equal to $\{a,b\}^*$ if no further restrictions on $x,y$ are imposed (consider $x=\varepsilon $). Then $L_1 =\varnothing$ (always) which is trivially regular.